# Manipulate an array to fetch a collection of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, google-apps-script

I'm trying to manipulate on an array and have stuck on how to actually do it.
I've created a calendar in Google Sheets using App Script, then I fetch all events (i.e. cells' notes) happening across given time frame and would like to divide the data to get person's name and all events that person will be responsible for.

```
function getEvents(){ 
  var numRows = range.getNumRows(); 
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns(); 
  var trainingTable = [] 
  var note, cell 
  for (var i = 3; i <= numRows; i++) { 
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) { 
      cell = range.getCell(i,j) 
      note = cell.getNote(); 

      //if the cell has a note push it into table
      if(note){ 
        trainingTable.push(note.split('\n')) 
        /* output 
        [ 
        [Ringo Starr, event 3, may 25], 
        [Paul McCartney, event 2, june 15], 
        [Ringo Starr, event X, february 2], 
        [George Harrison, event Y, may 25], 
        [Paul McCartney, event Z, june 15] 
        ] 
        up to 20 different people
        */
      } 
    } 
  } 
  for( var i in trainingTable ){
    // yes, what goes here?
    //how to distinct names and attach events to them
  }
}
```

I would like to create a profile object for each person and attach events as properties of these objects, but how to do so?

//Edit
As you see Ringo Starr has two different events, so the ideal profile would be: `var person1 = {name: Ringo Starr, e1: [event 3, may 25] , e2: [event X, february 2] }`

Thanks for any answer. 
Best.

Comment: `trainingTable[i][0]` is name, `trainingTable[i][1]` is event and `trainingTable[i][2]` is date,

Comment: Yes, obviously :) but I need to create a profile for each of the workers, Ringo Starr has two different events, so the ideal profile would be:
`var person1 = {name: Ringo Starr,
e1: [event 3, may 25] ,
e2: [event X, february 2] 
}`

Comment: It is only obvious to you. it is obvious to no one else because you didn't disclose what is obvious to you. If you are going to slow roll your requirements, your experience here won't go so well. Assumptions on our part are not your requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. Apologies.

Comment: Please edit your question to include "_the ideal profile_".

Comment: I apologize because this my comment is not the direct solution of your issue. In your script, ``getNote()`` is used for retrieving notes. In this case, the process cost becomes high. So for example, how about using [``getNotes()``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnotes)? By this, the cost can be reduced. And when you provide a sample Spreadsheet, I think that it will help users think of your solution and modification. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike!  Actually I get warning in the GAS editor that getValue/getNote have high utilisation cost - I work towards exchanging it with getNotes/getValues array.

Answer (score 0):

This searches the profile array for the artist name. If it can't find it(-1) then it creates a new p object and adds it to the profile array. If it does find the artist name, it simply adds the new event and date to the corresponding arrays within the artists profile.

```js
        trainingTable = [ 
        ["Ringo Starr", "event 3", "may 25"], 
        ["Paul McCartney", "event 2", "june 15"], 
        ["Ringo Starr", "event X", "february 2"], 
        ["George Harrison", "event Y", "may 25"], 
        ["Paul McCartney", "event Z", "june 15"] 
        ] ;

        var profile = [];
        for(x=0; x<trainingTable.length; x++) {
            t = trainingTable[x];
            var nameIndex = profile.findIndex(n => n.name === trainingTable[x][0]);
            if(nameIndex === -1) { 
                p = {
                    "name" : trainingTable[x][0],
                    "event" : [trainingTable[x][1]],
                    "date" : [trainingTable[x][2]]
                }
                profile.push(p);
            } else {
                profile[nameIndex].event.push(trainingTable[x][1]);
                profile[nameIndex].date.push(trainingTable[x][2]);  
            }
        }

        var person1 = profile[0];
        console.log(person1);
```